# how can i stop autosuggest ajax calls from coming back in wrong order?

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I'm using angular and I have an `ng-keyup` that fires when a user types in the field. The problem I'm noticing is that sometimes the first character's api call will come back after the 2nd character was typed and overwrite its results.

```
<input type="text"
       id="{{inputId}}"
       name="{{name}}"
       ng-model="newItem"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
       ng-paste="search({ $event: $event })"
       ng-keyup="search({ $event: $event })"
       ng-focus="newItem.length && search({ $event: $event })"
       ng-class="{ 'has-results': matches.length }"
       require-items="{{isValid}}"
       mongoose-error>
```

I need someway to not send the `search()` call if one is already being processed.

Comment: Look at [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive, then you may not have to use ng-keyup. Maybe debounce effect may work.

Comment: Why not maintain a simple flag, that can be used to keep a track whether an ajax call is already in queue ??

Comment: because i can't really skip them. if someone types "CAL" and "L" is skipped, I want it to still populate.